# Write a unit test class for an existing function that requires mockup within the function

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I have a bunch of PHP functions that require unit test classes to be written.
I just want to know is there any way to mock-up lines of a function before use assertions?

```
<?php 

function get_Func($args){
    $number = $args[0];
    $id = "71".$args[1]."0";

//The Line I need to mockup without touching the code
    $result = getViaCurl($number,$id);

    return $result;
}

?>
```

Comment: I am guessing the `$id = "71"+$args[1]+"0";` is trying to Concatenate and not do Addition! So the PHP concatenator is a `.` (dot) and not a `+` (plus sign)

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the function to a service, so you can mock it easily, but as long as your function is inside a class, because this way you can pass the new service to the class constructor to be able to pass the mock in the test, instead of the original.

```
class YourClass
{
    private NewService $service;

    public function __construct($service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }


    function get_Func($args)
    {
        $number = $args[0];
        $id = "71".$args[1]."0";

        //The Line I need to mockup without touching the code
        $result = $this->service->getViaCurl();

        return $result;
    }
}

class NewService
{
    public function getViaCurl($number, $id)
    {
        return getViaCurl($number,$id);
    }
}
```